# Swift: return tableview cell width wrong

Tags: swift, uitableview, frame

This is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyChatCell

    if(x){
        cell.width = 100
    } else {
        cell.width = 300
    }
}
```

And I manage by below code :

```
class MyChatCell: UITableViewCell {
    var width: Int = 0

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame = newFrame
            var newWidth = frame.width
            if(width > 0){
                newWidth = CGFloat(width)
            }

            frame.size.width = newWidth

            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

This code work, but some times on reload data or scroll table, width not set correct for that cell row

This is sample for normal view :

=======one=======

===two===

If i scroll or reload data show below view :

=======one=======

=======two=======

Comment: What is `x` in if statement?

Comment: @RobertDresler it is not matter. I want only say table one width different from table two